# Using a SQL Query Result in another Query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, datagridview

so I am filling a combobox with a listing of names. Now after clicking on one of those names I execute

```
SELECT Id FROM FIRSTTABLE WHERE Name ='" + ClientComboBox.Text + "'
```

Now I want to take that Id and execute another Sql query in SECONDTABLE. However, in that SECONDTABLE Id is called ClientId. Also I want to only populate the datagridview once. So I don't want to event show the FIRSTTABLE results, only what I get from the SECONDTABLE results. Not sure if that all made sense, so if you have any questions let me know.

```
private void ClientComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var myConnection = new SqlConnection(DBConnectionBox.Text);
            //myConnection.Open();


            var Cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id FROM FIRSTTABLE WHERE Name ='" + ClientComboBox.Text + "';");
            Cmd.Connection = myConnection;
            Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            var Cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SECONDTABLE WHERE ClientId ='"+"';");
            Cmd2.Connection = myConnection;
            Cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap2 = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd2);

            DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
            DataTable dtRecord2 = new DataTable();

            sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
            sqlDataAdap2.Fill(dtRecord2);

            ClientInfoDGV.DataSource = dtRecord;
            ClientInfoDGV.DataSource = dtRecord2;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use an inner join.

```
var Cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT Id, SECONDTABLE.* FROM FIRSTTABLE
   JOIN SECONDTABLE ON FIRSTTABLE.Id = SECONDTABLE.ClientId  
   WHERE Name ='" + ClientComboBox.Text + "';")
```

Comment: What if in first table Id's are duplicated and the result will have duplicate values from Second table.

Comment: True, I assumed that the first table's id field was unique, but I feel this is a safe assumption; given that he hadn't attempted a join, it's most likely the primary/unique column.

Comment: I always prefer join when I want to show data from both the tables :) else I will go with `exists`. Just a personal preference nothing wrong with your Join method unless Id's are duplicated

Comment: When I do that, it says "The multi-part identifier "Client.Id" could not be bound." Any idea on why this would be?

Comment: That means it can't find the column Id in the Client table. Without knowing the table structure, I can't really help you more than that.

Comment: @RichardTheobald you are absolutely right. I fat fingered something. Note to self, don't code at midnight with no energy drinks. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @RichardTheobald so if I wanted to select specific things from the SECONDTABLE, I would just replace * with the specific things I want?

Comment: Correct. It'd be similar to `SECONDTABLE.Column1, SECONDTABLE.Column2` etc.

Comment: So I would have to have saw SECONDTABLE.Name, SECONDTABLE.Address? I couldn't do SECONDTABLE Name, Address similar to how you would do SELECT Name, Address FROM SECONDTABLE.

Comment: The `SECONDTABLE` part is actually relevant only if the column is in both tables. It's not necessary, but just good practice. So you could totally do `Select Name, Address` if you wanted, so long as the column exists only in one of the two tables.

Comment: Interesting. I will just stick with the SECONDTABLE even though the information I want is only in that SECONDTABLE. So question. Could I take this query and say put it to execute on a button click instead of SelectedIndexChanged?

Comment: Presumably yes, but I don't actually know c# very well, so you'd have to try to be sure. I'm a PHP programmer. I got here from the mysql tag.

Comment: Hey @RichardTheobald could I add a third table into this? And that third table would reference a column in the SECONDTABLE.

Comment: Just add another join clause before the where clause. E.g. `SELECT Id, SECONDTABLE.*, THIRDTABLE.* FROM FIRSTTABLE
   JOIN SECONDTABLE ON FIRSTTABLE.Id = SECONDTABLE.ClientId JOIN THIRDTABLE on SECONDTABLE.Column = THIRDTABLE.Column WHERE Name =...`

Answer (score 0):

Like this in single query

```
SELECT * 
FROM   secondtable 
WHERE  clientid IN (SELECT f.id 
                    FROM   firsttable f
                    WHERE  f.NAME = "clientcombobox.text")
```

or `Exists` (Preferable)

```
SELECT * 
FROM   secondtable s 
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT 1 
              FROM   firsttable f 
              WHERE  s.clientid = f.id 
                     AND f.NAME = "clientcombobox.text")
```

Comment: When I do this, I get Incorrect syntaxt near ';' for the ; after sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);